# How can I implement carousel as in fb stories react js

Tags: reactjs, slider, carousel, owl-carousel, react-slick

Can anybody give me any source, How can I implement a react carousel like facebook stories? with the nav button effect that I have marked in the image.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for react-insta-stories its a library similar to your requirements and you can get create carousel with ease.

Comment: To improve your answer, you should provide the link to the library yourself.